# how to handle small change requests in the automated deployment process

Tags: agile, git, automation, gitflow, gitlab

I've setup a Gitlab server to manage several different Laravel Apps. I'm also able to configure the Gitlab CI to deploy the code to the development and production sites. Everything is kind of streamlined.

The problem is Clients want to make many small text changes in the view files. Most of them are fixing the grammatical errors or changing the heading wordings etc in the user interface. And we cannot wait until the next feature deployment to push these changes.

How do I manage these change requests? Do I need to make a separate commit for each of these changes and go through the automated deployment process? or is there any better way to handle this?

Comment: What is your objection to making a commit and auto deploying?

Comment: I'm trying to find if there is a better ways to do this. Is it a normal process in all the projects (to have very small changes added in separate commits)?

Comment: It is a thing. But if you are using the gitflow commit strategy and build on commits to develop and deploy commits to master you will get your 'don't build every tiny commit' and can do hotfixes for the immediately needed changes

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I recommend learning about common git workflow. https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html

Answer (score 2):

If these are only grammatical and spelling changes and very frequent then you can setup a quick **CACHE** that serves only Resource Bundle changes. 
Use **key:values** for all your texts and serve them via a DB table of resource **keys:values**. Make a system cache of that table and set a refreshing time (as per your need). So now **you don't have to commit or restart your server** anytime.
Whenever client ask for any change in text, update it in DB and wait for cache refresher.
Also if you want to make it more easy and delegate this task to client and focus on your dev tasks, Make a CRUD screen on your admin web and attach it with **Resource Bundle** table.

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about grammatical and spelling mistakes so it sounds like there is no need for hot fixes.

You can setup period deployment for such low priority fixes. You can collect them and release a new update once a month or before the next big release.